# Calculate accuracy function in ShuffleNet

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I'm using some code of ShuffleNet, but I have a problem with understanding the calculation of `correct` in this function.(this function calculates precision 1 and 5).
As I understand in the third line `pred` is the indices, but I can't understand why two lines later with equivalence function it has been compared with the `target`, because `pred` is indices of the most probabilities of output.

```
def accuracy(output, target, topk=(1,)):
    maxk = max(topk)
    batch_size = target.size(0)
    _, pred = output.topk(maxk, 1, True, True)
    pred = pred.t()
    correct = pred.eq(target.view(1, -1).expand_as(pred))

    res = []
    for k in topk:
        correct_k = correct[:k].contiguous().view(-1).float().sum(0)
        res.append(correct_k.mul_(100.0/batch_size))
    return res
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code, I can speculate `output` to be shaped `(batch_size, n_logits)` while the target is a dense representation: shaped `(batch_size, 1)`. This means the ground truth class is designated by an integer value: the corresponding class label.

If we look into this implementation of the top-`k` accuracy, we first need to understand this: top-`k` accuracy is about counting how many ground truth labels are among the *k* highest predictions of our output.  It's essentially a generalized form of the standard top-`1` accuracy where we would only look at the single highest prediction and find out if it matches the target.

If we take a simple example with `batch_size=2`, `n_logits=10`, and `k=3` *i.e.* we're interested in the top-`3` accuracy. Here we sample a random prediction:

```
>>> output
tensor([[0.2110, 0.9992, 0.0597, 0.9557, 0.8316, 0.8407, 0.8398, 0.3631, 0.2889, 0.3226],
        [0.6811, 0.2932, 0.2117, 0.6522, 0.2734, 0.8841, 0.0336, 0.7357, 0.9232, 0.2633]])
```

We first look at the *`k`* highest logits and retrieve their indices:

```
>>> _, pred = output.topk(k=3, dim=1, largest=True, sorted=True)

>>> pred
tensor([[3, 6, 4],
        [7, 3, 5]])
```

<sub>This is nothing more than a sliced [`torch.argsort`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.argsort.html): `output.argsort(1, descending=True)[:, :3]` will return the same result.</sub>

We can then transpose to get batches last `(3, 2)`:

```
>>> pred = pred.T
tensor([[3, 7],
        [6, 3],
        [4, 5]])
```

Now that we have the top-`k` predictions for each batch element, we need to compare those with the ground truths. Let us imagine now a target tensor (remember is shaped as `(batch_size=2, 1)`):

```
>>> target
tensor([[1],
        [5]])
```

We first need to expand it to the shape of `pred`:

```
>>> target.view(1, -1).expand_as(pred)
tensor([[1, 0],
        [1, 0],
        [1, 0]])
```

We then compare eachother with [`torch.eq`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.eq.html), the element-wise equality operator:

```
>>> correct = torch.eq(pred, target.view(1, -1).expand_as(pred))
tensor([[False, False],
        [False, False],
        [False,  True]])
```

As you can tell on the 2nd batch element, one of the highest three matches the ground-truth class label `5`. On the first batch element, neither of the three highest predictions matches the ground-truth label, it's not correct. The second batch element counts as one *'correct'*.

Of course, based on this equality mask tensor `correct`, you can slice it even more, to compute other top-`k'` accuracies where `k' <= k`. For instance `k' = 1`:

```
>>> correct[:1]
tensor([[False, False]])
```

Here for the top-`1` accuracy, we have zero correct instances out of the two batch elements.